# An alternative way of implemening navigation properties in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

The official approach to defining navigation properties for complex entities is:

```
public class SuperEntity
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}

public class LowerEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SuperEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual SuperEntity SuperEntity { get; set; }    
    //Other properties
}
```

The main thing here is that a class that references (allows navigation to linked super entity) has both `public SuperEntity SuperEntity { get; set; }` property, as well as it's Id in `public int SuperEntityId { get; set; }`.

I have gone a few days into my entities design ommiting the  `public int SuperEntityId { get; set; }` property in the "lower entities". So I am navigating only by virtual SuperEntity property. And everything works fine! But I had people on SO telling me that it creates an excessive tables in the DB. I've checked, and that is not true. When I use my approach, the DB tables has the SuperEntityId column and just populates it with the referenced entity Id automatically. What's the point in this `public int SuperEntityId { get; set; }` field then?

Or, perhaps, what I am doing became available in a "fresh" versions of EF like 4.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of SuperEntityId is that it is sometimes easier to use a foreign key property in apps where your context isn't alive the entire time, e.g. a webapp. 
In such a situation, it's a lot easier to just use a foreign key property, than to try to attach object B to object A.
As far as I know, with nav properties, EF uses an object to track the relation between 2 objects. So if you want to couple object B to object A, in a disconnected app, it's not enough to just set the property on object A, you also have to fiddle with the entry of object A in the changetracker to register the relation between B and A.
Setting a foreign key property is the equivalent of this fiddling.
When we were just beginning with EF and didn't know about all of this, every time we wanted to connect 2 objects, e.g. B to A, and B already existed in the DB, the context thought that B was a new object instead of an existing one, and duplicated the record in the DB.

Comment: Maybe you are right and I may stumple upon the problem later. Thanks.

Comment: Chances are that if your objects are floating around in the same context instance and never have to be explicitly attached (which is usually not required in a desktop app), you'll never really have much of a problem.

Comment: Just today I noticed in my test database that I had some duplicate records. They were exact duplicates including the relationships defined in the many to many bridge tables. I was puzzled but simply deleted them thinking it might have been an issue with the new Local DB. What you described is much more plausible and I am thinking on ditching navigation properties all together.

Answer (score 0):

It won't create excessive *tables*, but it will probably generate extra, or longer, queries on that database. But that depends on how you're using these entities.